# How do I correct the Build error after loading Glass.GlassMapper.sc.100 cannot find path Glass.Mapper.Sc.Start.config?

Tags: glass-mapper

After loading Glass.Mapper.sc.100 and Glass.Mapper.sc.100.mvc (Sitecore version 10) I can no longer build successfully. I am not certain how to resolve this issue. I have loaded and reloaded the Nuget Packages. I have unloaded the project from the solution. there does not seem to be any indicators in the .csproj file. The path exists in my target directory. here is the actual build error:

Here is a text format of the error:

```
1>Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
1>obj\Debug\net48\Package\PackageTmp.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3000,5): error : Copying file obj\Debug\net48\NuGet\DD3A9BE7C0EDA549CD5B7B690E0621F0E2C932EC\Glass.Mapper.Sc.100\5.8.173\App_Config/Include/Glass/Glass.Mapper.Sc.Start.config to obj\Debug\net48\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Debug\net48\NuGet\DD3A9BE7C0EDA549CD5B7B690E0621F0E2C932EC\Glass.Mapper.Sc.100\5.8.173\App_Config/Include/Glass/Glass.Mapper.Sc.Start.config failed. Could not find a part of the path 'obj\Debug\net48\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Debug\net48\NuGet\DD3A9BE7C0EDA549CD5B7B690E0621F0E2C932EC\Glass.Mapper.Sc.100\5.8.173\App_Config/Include/Glass/Glass.Mapper.Sc.Start.config'.
1>Done building project "Some.Project.ORM.csproj" -- FAILED.
```

[image]

Here is the .csproj :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>Some.Project.ORM</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Some.Project.ORM</AssemblyName>
    <PublishTargetType>website</PublishTargetType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\_Build\props\_PublishTargetType.props" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Glass.Mapper.Sc.100" Version="5.8.173" />
    <PackageReference Include="Glass.Mapper.Sc.100.Mvc" Version="5.8.173" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="App_Config\Include\Foundation\Glass\Glass.Mapper.Sc.Start.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Add error message in text format instead of screenshot

Comment: In your error snapshot, till the last line of error, the paths have all backward slashes "\" and then forward slashes "/" in last line. Can that be an issue.

Comment: @Ghanendra I will check that out. thank you. for the record I opened this solution and tried to build it from a cloned solution on my company's github account. so, i assumed it was correct

Comment: @Ghanendra this issue was because the file that I was copying to was over the 260 limit in VS. My path length was 261. We copying the solution to a shorter path and the build worked fine. thanks for your help.